# Automatically zooming to stat_summary data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to zoom in on a part of ggplot's graph to focus on the summary
statistics.

Let's say we have some data --

```
data = data.frame(x = c(1,2), y=c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11))
```

-- and we want to plot only the means --

```
qplot(x, y, data=data)
+ stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point",color="red")
```

Normally, I would use `scale_y_continuous(limits=...)`, but when using
`stat_summary` this drops some of the data (see `?stat_summary`).

So, I would want to use `coord_cartesian(ylim=...)`. But, this requires manually
specifying y limits, and it seems to zoom in on part of the graph, which can
leave less sensible background grid --

```
+ coord_cartesian(ylim=c(4.5,7.5))
```

-- in this example, filling in only the 6 as a tick mark.

How can one 'shrink-wrap' to zoom in on only `stat_summary`'s displayed data,
without specifying limits manually and changing the background grid?

(I actually want to do this with means and confidence intervals, so I would like to use `stat_summary`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently it is impossible to automatically zoom after stat_summary.
As for the ticks and breaks, you can use wise=TRUE in coord_cartesian in ggplot-0.8.9.

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(1,2), y=c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11))
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point",color="red") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(4.5,7.5), wise=TRUE)
```

also see the recent post of the blog:
http://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/24/zoom-with-break-adjustment-in-ggplot2/

Comment: Thanks -- the wise option works. Any tips on how to choose nice y-limits so the data remain vertically centered?

Comment: This should be fixed in the next version